# Debian autossh boot script not working properly

Tags: shell-script, networking, ssh, boot, init-script

I wrote the start script at the bottom of this question to try to get one of my devices to automatically create several remote forwarded ports with my VPS upon boot. (I've stripped the LSB tags to keep it to the point, but they're valid.) I do not receive any errors when running the script. It does create the autossh processes, but it does not make any connection to the VPS. (The client is a Raspberry Pi running Debian Wheezy, VPS is Ubuntu Server 14.10.) The `ssh` command used alone **does** work properly, so I don't know why the start script would not work. One thing I noticed (if you look below) is that the `-f` flag is being completely removed from the process when I use the script, but it remains when I just call `ssh`. PuTTY does flag the `-f` in green, differently than the rest of the text, but my Googling hasn't been able to tell me why it happens or if it's related to the problem. (Note: All port numbers are changed but still relate to each other correctly.)

My public key is correct, and the remote host is in `known_hosts` of both `user` and `root`. I tried escaping and not escaping the `-o` parameters, that made no difference, and escaping/using quotes around the `-f` flag made no difference either.

**UPDATE**: syslog is showing `ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh` for each autossh line, even though running the individual commands just as ssh (not autossh) works correctly. That error is returned whether the script is run or if I run the line from the script directly in bash.

Relevant part of the `init.d` script:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Creating SSH tunnels"
    autossh -M 0 -f -N -o \"ServerAliveInterval 60\" -o \"ServerAliveCountMax 3\" -R 11111:localhost:22222 -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -p 3333 user@server_ip
    #same command repeated twice more, everything exactly the same but with different ports
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping SSH tunnels..."
    ps axf | grep autossh | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/autossh-gen.sh {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

This causes three lines to appear when `ps aux | grep autossh` is run, but I'll put only one here for brevity. No actual connection is made to the remote server; the port remains closed. Notice that the `-f` command in the script is not present.

```
root     14137  0.0  0.1   1700   976 ?        Ss   01:37   0:00 /usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M 0    -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 11111:localhost:22222 -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -p 3333 user@server_ip
```

If I run just this ssh command...

```
ssh -f -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 11111:localhost:22222 -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -p 3333 user@server_ip
```

... then this is output to `ps aux` and the port **is** successfully forwarded.

```
root     14124  0.0  0.1   5728  1720 ?        Ss   01:31   0:00 ssh -f -N -o ServerAliveInterval 60 -o ServerAliveCountMax 3 -R 11111:localhost:22222 -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -p 3333 user@server_ip
```

Comment: Note that the manpage states *The -f flag is stripped from arguments passed to ssh.*

Comment: @wurtel I did see that, but it should still appear in the process list, shouldn't it? The process list shows the `autossh` command, not the `ssh` command. (Honest question, not saying you're wrong.)

Comment: It's showing `/usr/lib/autossh/autossh`, not `/usr/bin/autossh`. It doesn't pass the `-f` option to this helper process. Have you checked syslog for messages from `autossh`?

Comment: @wurtel syslog is showing `ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh` for each `autossh` line, even though running the individual commands just as `ssh` works correctly. That error is returned whether the script is run or if I run the line from the script directly in bash.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh exited with error status 255` usually points out authentication or connectivity issues. Try running your `autossh` without `-f` option so you can see its output:

```
autossh -M 0 -N -o \"ServerAliveInterval 60\" -o \"ServerAliveCountMax 3\" -R 11111:localhost:22222 -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -p 3333 user@server_ip
```

Out of `autossh` manual:

> Note that there is a crucial a difference between `-f` with autossh, and `-f` with ssh: when used with `autossh` *ssh will be unable to ask for passwords or passphrases*.

You can also try passing `-v` or `-vv` options to `ssh` to help your debug:

```
autossh -M 0 -N -vv -o \"ServerAliveInterval 60\" -o \"ServerAliveCountMax 3\" -R 11111:localhost:22222 -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -p 3333 user@server_ip
```

Also, please note that `/usr/lib/autossh/autossh` is the process that monitors your `ssh` session, and restarts it if required. If your `autossh` command it's working you should be able to see both `autossh` and `ssh` process:

```
$ps -eo user,pid,args | grep ssh
----------
someuser    16384  /usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M 33332    -N -R 11111:127.0.0.1:22222 serverip
someuser    16385  /usr/bin/ssh -L 33332:127.0.0.1:33332 -R 33332:127.0.0.1:33333 -N -R 11111:127.0.0.1:22222 serverip
```

And btw, you don't need to pass the `-f` option to `ssh`, `autossh` will start it in background, by default.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the init script is running under a different user context than when you try it manually. If the  init script is running with different userid, then check if the private key file can be read correctly.

There are known configuration issues on key files and their permissions.

The user who is executing the ssh command needs access to the identity file and, ssh can be strict in this, that the user owns the file, the .ssh directory and that the permissions are 700 for the .ssh directory and 600 for the private key file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I changed your "comment" to a potential answer, stating your questions as assumptions. Please flesh out the answer by providing the description of the known configuration issues, possible supported with some external links.

Comment: @HalosGhost, my reputation does not allow me to comment on other's answers, hence the new answer.

Comment: @Lambert It doesn't take long to build up the rep needed. In the future, restrain yourself from such posts until you do have the rep. That's the point.

Comment: @HalosGhost, I get your point, but (just curious) why do you think my answer is not the right one? I tried to help the author with another possibility since issues on private/public keys are common.

Comment: Now that it has been rewritten as an answer, I don't mind it at all.